# JDBC Insert after Delete slows down performance

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I run JDBC queries in a sequence `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE` etc. I insert one million of records in 1000 batches then delete those million records in single query then insert it again. In this case I am interested only in insertion performance.

When I run in in a loop of i.e. 10 iterations, at 1st iteration the performance is fastest i.e. 11 seconds then after every next iteration performance of insert is few seconds slower then the previous one. However, when I run it not in the loop the insertion time is very similar.

Any idea why?

```
for(number of iterations){
      //process insert of million records here, batch size is 1000
      //prepared statement is used and clearBatch is called after every 1000     
      //inserts,
      //at the end prepared statement is closed and connection.commit() is  
      //called

      //Thread.sleep(1000) called here
      //everything is inserted now in the DB so delete what has been inserted  
      //in single query. connection.commit() called again after delete.

      //Thread.sleep(1000) and repeat the same actions until loop finishes.
}
```

Sorry, I don't have the code with me.

Any idea why at every next iteration the insertion is slower?

Comment: Are you running it in one transaction?

Comment: No, I insert it 1000 by 1000 using one PreparedStatement object. With different batch size the time will also increase at every iteration. With one million in single transaction too.

Comment: Is it remote or local DB? Are there any indexes on the table? Can you try to replace DELETE with TRUNCATE?

Comment: It is remote DB, not sure about indexing. I'll try TRUNCATE and see if it makes any change.

Comment: unfortunately, cannot test it with truncate as there is other data already in DB which I can't remove.

Comment: I was wondering if there might be some possibility that at some point the db resource would not be released immediately etc. ? But I guess invoking commit would handle this. Do I need to invoke connection.commit() after DELETE?

Comment: Well that depends on your DataSource setting... if you don't use auto-commit then you have to commit explicitely. But I would need to see the code to give more insight. It can be caused by many different things.

Comment: Also do you have any monitoring tools for the DB? (look for AWR or statspacks)

Comment: I set auto-commit to false by default to I guess it's fine to invoke commit after delete.

Comment: I'll try use monitoring tools but today I'm not able to do it. What is interesting is that when I run that not in the loop but i.e. 10 times manually then times are very similar.

Comment: You say clearBatch() is called after every 1000 inserts, but that would be after a million records, so it only happens once. So why do it at all?

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure without the code, but I think you have a memory leak so that the extra time is due to garbage collection. That would explain why it is faster to run the same code several times without a loop. Run the program with GC logging enabled (-XX:+PrintGC) and see what happens.

To eliminate database issues you may want to test with another (new) table and replace the delete with truncate table, just in case.